# Writring to file in Windows 8 using Javascript

Tags: windows-8

I'm creating a Windows 8 application and i need to store some Data about the application in a text file inside the Application , i found this useful tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464978.aspx   but it use a know folder to store the file in my case i want to store it inside the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found the answer , you can get The location using

```
 Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

and then using it in Writing and Reading From and to Files

[This link is useful](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx#Y735)